# DataContext and CommittableTransaction

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, transactions, datacontext

I am aware Linq to Sql DataContexts can participate in transactions using the TransactionScope way, which sets the ambient transaction to which the DataContext enlists automatically.

However I am in need of using an explicit Transaction using a CommittableTransaction object. I am also aware I can explicitly set the DbTransaction property on DataContext to a transaction object, which would also serve my purpose, but I am interested in finding a way out to have DataContext enlist to a CommittableTransaction.

There must be some way of doing it as when using TransactionScope, the ambient Transaction is set and DataContext enlists to it. Even SqlConnection object exposes the EnlistTransaction method that be used for enlisting to a CommittableTransaction. However I am unable to find a way to have DataContext enlist to a CommittableTransaction explicitly.

Comment: `Transaction.Current = yourCommittableTransaction`.

Comment: @GertArnold, well that's the point. I can not use ambient transaction (setting it explicitly is as good as using TransactionScope with appropriate modifiers). Deeply nested code would be invoked as a result of my calls which themself use Contexts and would thus participate in same transaction as mine (they do not use TransactionScope and would thus get automatically enlisted).I know I can use TransactionScope with "Suppress" in nested code,but that's lot of refactoring and QA.Like I said,I can use the DbTransaction property,I am interested in CommittableTransaction as an academic exercise too.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. You seem to suggest you want to mimic `TransactionScope` behaviour with `CommittableTransaction`. (_There must be some way of doing it as when using TransactionScope_). Do you want to keep connections out of the transaction?

Comment: I am not exactly trying to mimic TransactionScope. Obviously with TransactionScope, Transaction.Current is set but DataContext must be doing something to enlist to it, so something like if(Transaction.Current!=null) {this.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current)}. SqlConnection has an EnlistTransaction method, I am trying to figure out a similar approach for DataContext.